# RDWeb issue with two servers

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdweb

I am working on customizing the RDWeb application for Remote Desktop Service for Windows Server 2012.

The description of the implementation of this project is as follows.

1. I have configured two seperate servers for RDWeb.
2. The RDWeb application is generated for both the servers.
3. I am accessing the RemoteApp of second server using the RDWeb application of first server through single UI. RemoteApp from both servers are comming into single UI.
4. Now suppose I have two Calculator applications, one from each server, *Cal1* and Cal2. When I click on *Cal1* then Calculator runs from the first server without asking for any credential. When I click on *Cal2*, then it asks for credential. If I provide the credentials, then the calculator application from the second server runs.

My problem is that when I click on *Cal2*, it should not ask for credentials. The RDWeb application is auto generated and uses form authentication. For this I need to share cookies between both the servers. I have used the same machine key in the `web.config` of both the applications but that is not working.

It would be helpfull if you can provide me with some guidance for this issue.

Comment: I'm confused. Are the servers running RDWeb and acting as your Session Hosts?

Comment: Thanks GregL for your prompt reply, yes both the server are running RDWeb,but they are not working as session Hosts.
Both the servers are from different farms.I am trying to combine remote apps from both the server into single page.Iam able to do that,but now when i click on any remote app that are comming from other server its asking for credentials.while the credentials are not been asked for the remote app for the server running the RDWeb website.